# async waterfall not following order when mysql query

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to do a waterfall async but i don't get the expected output that i want. 
Basically my waterfall works as expected if i use an array instead of the query 
so i guess i am doing something wrong on the callback of the query but i don't know what.

Code when it works with what i expect using array:

```
    function range(start, end) {
    var foo = [];
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        foo.push(i);
    }
    return foo;
}
users = range(1,2)
obj = [1,2]; 
async.forEachLimit(users, 1, function(user, userCallback){
    async.waterfall(
        [
            function(callback) { // query the data to get the category and specific number  of rows
            results = {sku_config:'A',img:'http//blabla',sku_config:'B',img:'http//bloblo'}
            callback(null, results);


            },
            function(obj,callback) {
                async.eachSeries(obj, function (sku, callback) {
                    var url = sku.img;
                    var sku = sku.sku_config;
                    console.log("loop");
                            request.get(url, {encoding: null} , function(error, response, body) {
                                console.log('request');
                            });

                    callback(null);
                }, function(responsetoendofloop){
                        callback(null);
                });
            },
        ],
        function (err) {
            console.log('Finish');
            userCallback(null);
        }
    );
}, function(err){
    console.log("User For Loop Completed");
});
```

output:

```
loop
request
loop
request
Finish
loop
request
loop
request
Finish
User For Loop Completed
```

But when i try to query the data with mysql here comes the problem
code:

```
async.forEachLimit(users, 1, function(user, userCallback){
    async.waterfall(
        [
            function(callback) { // query the data to get the category and specific number  of rows
                connection.query(query_sku, 
                ['Fashion',1,2],
                    function(err, results, fields) {
                        if (err) 
                            throw err;
                 callback(null, results);
                });

            },
            function(obj,callback) {
                async.eachSeries(obj, function (sku, callback) {
                    var url = sku.img;
                    var sku = sku.sku_config;
                    console.log("loop");
                            request.get(url, {encoding: null} , function(error, response, body) {
                                console.log('request');
                            });

                    callback(null);
                }, function(responsetoendofloop){
                        callback(null);
                });
            },
        ],
        function (err) {
            console.log('Finish');
            userCallback(null);
        }
    );
}, function(err){
    console.log("User For Loop Completed");
});
```

output:

```
loop
loop
Finish
loop
loop
Finish
User For Loop Completed
request
request
request
request
```

All the request gets executed at the end :(

If you have idea on what i could fix.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you have is that your callbacks have the exact same name, this could cause major problems. The callbacks you are meaning to call can not be differentiated, which could cause your program to execute pieces of code that shouldn't be executed until later.

The second problem is that the callback is placed outside of the request.get function. The nature of node js means that it does not wait until the request.get function returns and instead just calls the callback straight away. By placing the callback inside of the request.get function it is forced to wait until the request function returns and then the callback is called. A revised version of your code is below.

```
 async.forEachLimit(users, 1, function(user, userCallback){
    async.waterfall(
    [
        function(callback) { // query the data to get the category and specific number  of rows
            connection.query(query_sku, 
            ['Fashion',1,2],
                function(err, results, fields) {
                    if (err) 
                        throw err;
                    callback(null, results);
            });

        },
        function(obj,callback) {
            async.eachSeries(obj, function (sku, seriesCallback) {
                var url = sku.img;
                var sku = sku.sku_config;
                console.log("loop");
                request.get(url, {encoding: null} , function(error, response, body) {
                    console.log('request');
                    seriesCallback(null);
                });

            }, function(responsetoendofloop){
                    callback(null);
            });
        },
    ],
    function (err) {
        console.log('Finish');
        userCallback(null);
    });
 }, function(err){
     console.log("User For Loop Completed");
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very clear! For your first point I was assuming that event though the name of the callback has the same name it respects the scope of each function. But I will take the good habit to rename them

Comment: You're welcome! Glad i could be of help to you! This may be true that the scope of callbacks is respected, however as you say it is definitely good practice to give them different names. This will definitely avoid confusion when multiple nested async methods are used and also allow you to actually specify the callback of a parent method if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `callback(null);` inside `async.eachSeries` are after request.

To fix just put inside request like this.

```
request.get(url, {encoding: null} , function(error, response, body) {
  console.log('request');
  callback(null);
});
```

Plus to be clear what you actually calling rename callback functions. For example callback inside `eachSeries` call `next`

```
function(obj,callback) {
     async.eachSeries(obj, function (sku, next) {
         var url = sku.img;
         var sku = sku.sku_config;
         console.log("loop");
         request.get(url, {encoding: null} , function(error, response, body) {
            console.log('request');
            next(null);
         });
    }, function(responsetoendofloop){
          callback(null);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.